# List/Database of U.S cities and states

Tags: database

I want a .csv list, mysql database, or any other list of all U.S states and cities, including which cities are in which state. From this list I will generate a mysql database with the following fields:

```
states:
 - id (int, auto_increment, primary)
 - name (varchar 255)

cities:
 - id (int, auto_increment, primary)
 - stateId (id of the state from states table to which this city belongs)
 - name (varchar 255)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is programming related as the list will be used to create a database and used programatically as i've explained.

Comment: You should think more about your proposed schema.  No US state has a name with a length approaching 255; size your name column more sensibly.  Ditto city names.  States have a 2-character abbreviation that makes a fine natural key; you don't need an integer autoincrement primary key.

Comment: @Leffler: I agree about the abbreviations for states, but the city names MUST allow for a margin of error, and should allow for full Unicode characters. A few city names may include weird characters from other languages, and you don't want to risk running out of characters when this happens.

Comment: @BobMcGee: the USPS doesn't allow for 'weird characters' in US city names, and the question is explicitly about US city and state names.

Comment: @Click Upvote: it depends on your DBMS.  I don't know the internals of MySQL, I can't say. However, on another DBMS I know of (in detail), overlong VARCHAR fields can lead to unnecessary fragmentation at the page level. With the state table, it would probably only mean that the data was split over one or two extra pages over the minimum possible - but that table is minute anyway.  There is also the 'validation' aspect; the DBMS won't ensure that the state names or (more importantly) city names are of the appropriate length. There are rules imposed by the USPS about how long city names can be.

Comment: @Leffler(1): How does Āhualoa, Hawaii grab you?  Also, it's not uncommon for a business to decide to include shipping to Canada (or at least the part of Canada near the border). In that case, it's a smart move to allow for both States and *Provinces* as well as peculiar characters in town names.  The USPS can do many wonderful things, but unfortunately their reach can't cross the border...
Planning for logical expansion is never a bad move, and the DB still won't be too big.

Comment: BobMcGee @Leffler There's also many Puerto Rican and Californian cities that have special characters, like the accented vowels in Spanish names, or the ñ character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [MySQL world sample database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/index.html).  This db is used by mysql documentation as a sample db to test query on.

It already have a 'cities' table you are looking for.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Update link is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/index.html

Comment: I don't know how useful a "sample" database will be when expecting a comprehensive and routinely updated list of cities.

Answer (score 94):

You can get city/state information in tab-separated value format from [GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org/).  The data is free, comprehensive and well structured.  For US data, grab the `US.txt` file at the [free postal code data](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/) page.  The `readme.txt` file on that page describes the format.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That site really is fantastic.

Comment: Note that these seem to be post-processed USPS names, and may not be  suitable for doing a direct city name validation.  For example, the city of "O'Brien, TX" appears in the database as "O BRIEN".

Comment: This has a 1-to-1 mapping of zip code to city, so it may not work depending on your use case.  You can always get Zip -> City, but not always City -> Zip if there are multiple towns within the same zip code.  If you're trying to validate city names, this won't work in all cases.

Answer (score 14):

I spent a while looking for such a file, and ended up doing one myself, you can get it from here:

https://github.com/grammakov/us_cities_and_states/tree/master

Comment: That's awesome and under-appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.

Comment: It would be nice to know the sources. The README just says "several sources". That could mean anything

Comment: Is there any option to get the state, county and zipcode as this?

Answer (score 6):

Are you ready to pay for this content?
If YES, then you can find it at **uscities.trumpetmarketing.net**

I have also seen this information provided along with some programming books especially ones dealing with .NET database programming. Let me refer to my library and ge back to you on this:

You can also refer the following:

http://www.world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?x=1129163518&men=stdl&lng=en&gln=xx&dat=32&srt=npan&col=aohdq

http://www.geobytes.com/FreeServices.htm

Please dont bother voting for this answer. There is no information here that cannot be obtained via a simple google search!

**Someone has posted a list here:**

**http://mhinze.com/archive/list-of-us-cities-all-city-names-and-states-regex-groups/**

Comment: upvoted just for being frank :)

Answer (score 2):

I use the [us city and county database](http://www.softwaremastercenter.com/us-city-and-county-list.html) for this purpose and I just checked that it got updated in August. They claim to include 198,703 populated places (a GNIS term for a city or village). I see you need full state names and these names are included in a free database called [us state list](http://www.softwaremastercenter.com/us-state-list.html).

Both of them are in CSV files and they provide very detailed instructions about how to import them to both local and remote MySQL servers. You can join them in a select statement to pull records with full state names for your needs.

Comment: Do you know of a more updated version? That page was cool at the time, but it's more than six years out of date by now and they don't seem to have a newer version.

Answer (score 2):

You can find csv or sql format  or  html format at below website. They have cities+states for some countries including usa.

http://www.countrystatecity.com/. They keep updating the site and doing good job. hope this will help to other developers also.

for usa you can check below link.

http://www.countrystatecity.com/USAStatesCities.php

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So I added the downloading link to US details.

Answer (score 1):

That's a tall order.  Consider creating one by scraping the links off this page:
[WP: List of cities, towns, and villages in the US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities,_towns,_and_villages_in_the_United_States).  It is much simpler if you scrape the wiki markup code rather than the raw HTML.

Will require some skill at regexes or at least parsers, but should be do-able.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me a great deal: http://www.farinspace.com/us-cities-and-state-sql-dump/

It has a .zip file with 3 .sql files which you can just run in ssms.

You may need to replace some of the weirdly encoded single quotes with double quotes.