# Where can I find a database of main U.S cities?

Tags: geolocation, state, country, city

I'm looking for a database containing the main cities in the U.S categorized be states.

Comment: "Main" cities?  What does that mean?

Comment: This doesn't sound much like a programming question.

Comment: Scrape them from here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states'_largest_cities_by_population

Comment: I agree that this is not a programmer's question, but you start coming this across quite often when developing, so it might probably help if programmers start sharing the experience in this area..

Comment: Sounds like the making of a lousy road trip...

Comment: Agree with Arthur.  This is definitely relevant for a lot of programmers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177831/list-database-of-u-s-cities-and-states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 'main', but here's  alist of
top 50 cities in the U.S. by population and rank

http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0763098.html#ixzz1QVw6vh6r

Answer (score 0):

I recently downloaded one from somewhere, I lost a source I got it from, but can export it for you if you're interested. Please let me know

Comment: Yes please, I'd appreciate it.