# How to find the county for each city in a vector of city names using R?

Tags: r, geolocation

Given a string of city names, how would one go about finding the county that each city belongs to using R? I've looked at the `map` and `acs` packages but I'm not experienced with them. The goal is to found county-level data to associate with the cities in my data.

Say you have the following:

```
city <- c("RALEIGH", "HOLLYWOOD", "DALLAS", "MOUNTAIN VIEW", "OKLAHOMA CITY", "ORLANDO")
state <- c("NC", "CA", "TX", "CA", "OK", "FL")
```

Comment: You could check `library(countrycode)`  Please consider to provide reproducible example.

Comment: @akrun updated with reproducible example

Comment: What you provided is not yet a reproducible example. The question looks more like a tool request. A reproducible example would be something along the lines of "I have tried this method, but keeps producing this error. How can I solve this problem or is it conceptually wrong and I need to look into something else".

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Well, I don't know what to try, which is what I'm asking suggestions for. I'm not sure where to begin. `library(countrycode)` doesn't look like it will work

Comment: Unfortunately the [tag:r] tag is not the best place to be looking for tools. Feel free to visit [R-public](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) and [GMTs](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75819/gmts) chatrooms to see if anyone can offer assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You can get city/state information in tab-separated value format from GeoNames.org. The data is free, comprehensive and well structured. For US data, grab the US.txt file at the free postal code data page. The readme.txt file on that page describes the format." 
[See post by Joshua Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177831/list-database-of-u-s-cities-and-states)

```
## Download the file

temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/US.zip",temp)
con <- unz(temp, "US.txt")
US <- read.delim(con, header=FALSE)
unlink(temp)

## Find state and county

colnames(US)[c(3,5,6)] <- c("city","state","county")
US$city <- tolower(US$city)
myCityNames <- tolower(c("RALEIGH", "HOLLYWOOD", "DALLAS", "MOUNTAIN VIEW","OKLAHOMA CITY", "ORLANDO"))
myCities <- US[US$city %in% myCityNames, ]
myCities <- myCities[c("city","state","county")]
myCities <- myCities[!duplicated(myCities),]
myCities <- myCities[order(myCities$city, myCities$state, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

The problem is that there are multiple cities with the same name in different states.

If you look exactly for the cities in the states you mentioned this might help:

```
myPlaces <- data.frame(city = myCityNames, state = c("NC", "CA", "TX", "CA", "OK", "FL"))
merge(myCities, myPlaces, by = c("city", "state") ,all.y=TRUE)
```

Comment: this sounds promising. i'll check it out tonight

Comment: GeoNames appears to be missing a non-negligible number of locations in the US. For instance, it's missing Amherst, NY, a city of 130,000 people.